# Poor performance in this code, how to make it better?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, numpy, cython

I'm trying to build a recommendation algorithm for a school project. At some point, I have this function, which is critical for performance. It returns the 5 items which have the highest similarity with the user. I did it three different ways.

(1), which I think is the most "pythonic" one, but is the slowest approach, it takes approximately 800ms to complete.

(2) is way uglier but unexpectedly faster (600ms), even though it adds a sorting operation.

Then, I did it like I would in old school C++ (3), and this is the fastest one, but not by much (550ms):

```
import math
import numpy as np
import pickle
import bisect

shrink=10
return_itemcount=5
target_users_list=[1,3,4]
already_rated_set={ 1: {1,2}, 3: {1}, 4: {5}}
user_features_dict={1: np.array([5,6]), 3: np.array([6,7]), 4: np.array([11])}
item_features_dict={1: np.array([6,7]), 2: np.array([7,8]), 3: np.array([6,11])}
items_set=set(item_features_dict.keys())

#(1)
def get_item_similarfeatures1(user):
    res=[]
    for item in items_set-already_rated_set[user]:
        bisect.insort(res,[useritem_similarity(user,item),item])
    return [x[1] if x[0]>0 else -1 for x in res[(-return_itemcount-1):]]

#(2)
def get_item_similarfeatures2(user):
    res={}
    for item in items_set-already_rated_set[user]:
        sim=useritem_similarity(user,item)
        if sim>0:
            res[item]=sim
    res=sorted(res.items(), key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)[0:5]
    return list(map(lambda x: x[0],res))

#(3)
def get_item_similarfeatures3(user):
    res=[(-1,0)]*return_itemcount
    threshold=0
    for item in (items_set-already_rated_set[user]):
        sim=useritem_similarity(user,item)        
        if sim>threshold:
            for idx, _ in enumerate(res):
                if _[1]<sim: 
                    res.insert(idx,(item,sim))
                    del res[return_itemcount]
                    threshold=res[return_itemcount-1][1]
                    break
    return list(map(lambda x: x[0],res))

def useritem_similarity(user,item):
    if ( user not in user_features_dict): return 0
    features_user=user_features_dict[user]
    features_item=item_features_dict[item]
    return np.in1d(features_user,features_item).sum()/np.sqrt(features_user.size*features_item.size+shrink)


feature_recommendations_dict={ user : get_item_similarfeatures1(user) for user in target_users_list}
feature_recommendations_dict
```

What I'd like to understand is:

- Why (2) is faster than (1)?

**EDIT:** This has been answered by [ali_m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1461210/ali-m) in the comments, I've updated the code following [gboffi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2749397/gboffi)'s suggestion:

```
def get_item_similarfeatures1(user):
    res=[[0,-1]]*return_itemcount
    for item in items_withfeatures_set-already_rated_set[user]:
        sim=useritem_similarity(user,item)
        if (sim>res[0][0] or res[return_itemcount-1][0]==0):
            bisect.insort(res,[sim,item])
            del res[0]
    return [x[1] if x[0]>0 else -1 for x in res[-return_itemcount-1:]]
```

but this still runs somewhat slower (580ms) than (3).

- Would it be worth to compile (3) or `useritem_similarity` in cython? Would it yield better performance?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] showing how these functions are called?

Comment: I've benchmarked them using `%timeit` in Jupyter, with the same user. Is this what you are asking? Anyway, they will be called inside this loop: `feature_recommendations_dict={ user : get_item_similarfeaturesN(user) for user in target_users_list}`

Comment: We need to be able to run this code ourselves to help. Show us how to run it, and what kind of data you're feeding in. A fully self-contained program (**complete**).

Comment: This question is better suited for [codereview.se] than this site.

Comment: I hope [this](https://pastebin.com/rVDc92Ax) is what you meant

Comment: *"Why (2) is faster than (1)?"* Using `bisect.insort` to maintain `res` in a sorted order on every loop iteration is almost certainly more expensive than sorting once outside the loop. Also, inserting into a Python list is *O(n)*, whereas setting an item in a dict has an average time complexity of *O(1)* (see https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a suggestion for you, that cannot be formulated inside the constraints of a comment.

What I think is that you're overdoing, you can just keep the best 5 results, like in this example I've constructed

```
In [1]: import bisect as bs

In [2]: from random import random, seed

In [3]: seed(8888)

In [4]: l = [random() for _ in range(100)]

In [5]: r = [0  for i in range(5)]

In [6]: for x in l:
   ...:     if x>r[0]:
   ...:         bs.insort(r, x)
   ...:         r.pop(0)
   ...:         

In [7]: print(r) ; print(sorted(l)[-5:])
[0.9734802621456982, 0.9764741228388244, 0.9806769811156987, 0.9820424903993659, 0.9884636482746705]
[0.9734802621456982, 0.9764741228388244, 0.9806769811156987, 0.9820424903993659, 0.9884636482746705]

In [8]:
```

Of course you should adapt this simple example to your, more complex, use case but avoiding moving tons of data (inserting and/or sorting) may help a lot.

Another possibility is the [`heapq` module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/heapq.html)

```
In [1]: from random import random, seed
In [2]: from heapq import heappushpop, heapreplace
In [3]: seed(8888)
In [4]: l = [random() for _ in range(100)]
In [5]: r = [0  for i in range(5)]
In [6]: for x in l:
   ...:     if x>r[0]: heapreplace(r, x)
In [7]: r
Out[7]: 
[0.9734802621456982,
 0.9764741228388244,
 0.9806769811156987,
 0.9820424903993659,
 0.9884636482746705]
In [8]:
```

Continuing with the possibilities offered by the `heapq` module,

```
In [10]: from heapq import nlargest
In [11]: nlargest(5, l)
Out[11]: 
[0.9884636482746705,
 0.9820424903993659,
 0.9806769811156987,
 0.9764741228388244,
 0.9734802621456982]
```

(the order is reversed).

While the timings of `heapreplace` are *slightly*  but consistently better than the `insort` timings, `nlargest` is significantly faster.

I don't quote timings because you must benchmark the different possibilities against *your* data, and please remember that the approach of storing all the results and eventually sorting may be faster than these above depending on the amount of data you are processing, as I've also mentioned in a comment.

Comment: I made some testing to find that for longer sequences the `insort()` wins hands down, for shorter sequences it's faster to collect all the results and eventually sort the whole sequence of results. — You'd better time different algorithms (say mine and yours no.2) for data sizes characteristic of your application domain. Ciao

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have several algorithms that perform what you need, you can now benchmark/time them, and thus find which has the best performance.

Then, you'd profile the winning code to find where its bottlenecks are.

And then, you'd use the techniques/tools I mention [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw5McUt95YdeMlNiX2VSR1lFRHM/view) to eliminate these bottlenecks.

I elaborate on each of the above, including going over the tools for each, in [my talk at PyCon](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw5McUt95YdeMlNiX2VSR1lFRHM/view).